# Using single Apache HttpClient instance for making multiple synchronous requests to multiple hosts (>500 requests)

Tags: java, rest, apache-httpclient-5.x

I need to make multiple GET requests to multiple hosts synchronously. The number of requests at the minimum is 500. Can I use a single Apache HttpClient instance to make all the requests? Or do I need to make a new one for each request? Any other method/library will also work.

Comment: You can use one instance. It's thread-safe.

Comment: I have a single thread but I need to make many requests

Comment: Then you have even less of a problem.